# Cases where the imports in Java aren't needed (unusual qualification) [Question Edited]

Tags: java, import, jls

I've noticed there are some special ways to qualify an entity in Java:

```
Object o = new Outer().new Inner();
```

In this case, we are qualifying the Inner class with the Outer class, so we only need to import the Outer class:

```
import mypackage.Outer;
```

Are there any other cases like this? (That is, where an *unusual* qualification occurs - by unusual I mean not: `fullQualifier.identifier`).

I'm excluding the case of the automatic imports (java.lang, primitive types, etc.)

Comment: This isn't automatic importing.  `import mypackage.Outer.Inner;` wouldn't be valid in this case.

Comment: I didn't say I was automatically importing, but you're right. `import mypackage.Outer.Inner;`, although not invalid, it is marked as unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the construct you've described:

```
Object o = new Outer().new Inner();
```

is actually a way to fully qualify the `Inner` class' constructor, just as in

```
Outer.Inner i = new Outer().new Inner();
```

On the other hand, you could write this:

```
import path.to.Outer;
import path.to.Outer.Inner;

// ...

Inner i = new Outer().new Inner();
```

Comment: You're right. I'm not fully qualifying the constructor (as I still have to import the `Outer` class), but I'm qualifying Inner. I only need to import Inner if I want to use it the way you use it in your last example. +1. Do you know if there are any more ways to qualify things, other than the normal name qualification?

Comment: @John, yes, the Java language syntax specification is very rich. E.g. you can qualify members/methods of the current type hierarchy with the `this` and `super` keywords. Then, the `this` keyword can be prepended with classes, narrowing the `this` context down to a more concrete class (useful when the `Inner` object wants to reference something from the `Outer` object, e.g. in `Outer.this.blah()`). For more details, check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: I also already knew that case. Do you know if nested cases are the only ones that have special qualification?

Comment: But my interest is only in qualification that messes with the imports. I can't use Outer.this, if Outer is not imported.

Comment: Hmm, maybe if I understood why you're looking for "special cases", I could understand what you're really looking for... Or is this just a general question "out of curiousity"? Because after 5-6 years of working with Java, these things do not appear extraordinarily *special* to me :-)

Comment: I guess, there is not much more to say... Maybe you find a more authoritative answer in the JLS: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/

Answer (score 1):

Also, you wouldn't need to import a class if:

- you use the full path to the object. For example:

  ```
  java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
  ```
- the class is in the same package
- the class is in the `java.lang` package e.g. `String`

Comment: Those are exactly the cases I know. :)
Are there any more? But +1.

Answer (score -1):

the outer package in this case included the inner package, thats why there was no need ti import the inner package, in most cases there is no need to import a whole package just to use one component ..for example i only want to use a String, there is no need ti import the whole java.lang. In some complicated libraries usage if you are using some IDEs they can fix the imports for you, for example in netbeans ctrl+shift+i will fix your imports

Comment: `Outer` and `Inner` are classes, not packages... John is aware of "automatic" imports of the `java.lang` package, I think he was just a bit surprised that he didn't need to import the `Inner` class in the constructor syntax he was using...